# SceneKit. How to achieve default scene light behavior without autoenablesDefaultLighting?

Tags: swift, scenekit

I tried to set `autoenablesDefaultLighting=true` for my SCNView and it looks good. However i want to achieve the same behavior without `autoenablesDefaultLighting` with setting light and adjust it a little bit.

I tried omni light with this code:

```
let lightNode = SCNNode()
lightNode.light = SCNLight()
lightNode.light?.castsShadow = true
lightNode.light?.type = .omni
lightNode.light?.intensity = 10000
lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 100)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)
```

And got this:

[image]

And with `autoenablesDefaultLighting=true` I got this:

[image]

Comment: you light intensity is way to high, set it from 10000 to 1000

Comment: Yeah. But you see the borders are black, but they should be like on the image with default lightning. So if I set it to 1000, they would be even darker, So how it would help?

Comment: you can use the light's bitmasks to define on what surfaces to shine. could you try a value of -1 for this light bitmask? (-1 meins to shine on everything). If not, would it be possible to share your project?

Comment: I think the default lighting is composed of a directional light and an ambiant light, not an omni light.

Answer (score 1):

### Custom Default Lighting

I believe, in SceneKit, the default scene lighting is a Directional Light without any shadows, attached directly to the default camera node (i.e. `pointOfView` node). To simulate the same lighting conditions as when the `.autoenablesDefaultLighting` property is `true`, use the following code:

[image]

Delegate's renderer method – light's position orientation will be updated 60 times per second:

```
import SceneKit

extension GameViewController: SCNSceneRendererDelegate {
    
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer,
           updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
        
        sunNode.transform = (sceneView?.pointOfView?.worldTransform)!
        
        let cameraAngles = (self.sceneView?.pointOfView?.eulerAngles)!
        let lightAngles = self.sunNode.eulerAngles
        
        print("Camera: " + String(format: "%.2f, %.2f, %.2f", cameraAngles.x,
                                                              cameraAngles.y,
                                                              cameraAngles.z))

        print("Light: " + String(format: "%.2f, %.2f, %.2f", lightAngles.x,
                                                             lightAngles.y,
                                                             lightAngles.z))
    }
}
```

Here's GameViewController class:

```
class GameViewController: NSViewController {
    
    var sceneView: SCNView? = nil
    let sunNode = SCNNode()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       
        sceneView = self.view as? SCNView
        sceneView?.delegate = self
        let scene = SCNScene(named: "ship.scn")!
        sceneView?.scene = scene
        
        sceneView?.scene?.lightingEnvironment.contents = .none
        sceneView?.scene?.background.contents = .none
        
        sceneView?.backgroundColor = .black
        sceneView?.allowsCameraControl = true
        // sceneView?.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
        
        sunNode.light = SCNLight()
        sunNode.light?.type = .directional
        sceneView?.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(sunNode)
    }
}
```

### Explanations

I'd like to add that if there is no light in the scene at all (including the `autoenablesDefaultLighting` parameter), then the only uncontrollable source of light in the scene will be the non-switchable Ambient Light.

In addition to the above, the Physically Based shader always requires additional Ambient Light fixture (otherwise the physically based surface will be black). The location and orientation of this light source does not matter.

If Directional Light illuminates the surface perpendicularly, then the surface is illuminated with 100% intensity (default intensity is 1000 lumens), but if the rays of the light source are parallel to the surface, then the surface is not illuminated by this source.

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the first and last images have identical lighting environment.

Comment: Maybe SceneKit changed but with default lighting I currenty see about 3 different reflections on a sphere, of different sizes (there might be more, it is occluded by some bigger object). With a directional light attached to the camera node I see only one, and it is really not the same.

Comment: It is quite possible that default SceneKit lighting uses three light sources. So the third light source is only used for reflections, not to change the light pattern.